# Launch an Remote Cordova App from a Local Cordova App

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a text field where I can enter the URL of an remote Cordova App which is running on a server.

Here is the code of my local Cordova app which is running on a cell phone

```
RemoteCordovaAppUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.RemoteCordovaAppUrl);
String urlString = RemoteCordovaAppUrl.getText().toString();
app.putExtra("appUri", urlString);
startActivity(app);
```

Here is the code of the remote Cordova app which is running on a server

```
  if (window.cordova) {
      console.log('You are on a cell phone');
  } else {
      console.log('You are on a browser');
  }
```

How to let the remote Cordova know that it is on a cell phone, so the remote Cordova can utilize cell phone's camera and other resources.

Comment: When you said that Cordova app is running in a server what do you mean? a server is emulating the app? if so what is the enviroment ?

Comment: By using ionic serve --address 192.168.1.100, the Cordova app can run as a server on its host whose ip is 192.168.1.100. The environment can be a Mac or a PC. When the Cordova app is running, I can visit the 192.168.1.100:8100 by my cell phone which is on the same local network.